# API Manager - Too many java threads

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are using API Manager to expose the underlying DSS services. The API Manager starts around 10 java threads in linux for every request/response from the client. But these threads stays there forever and eventually our server runs out of memory.

Shouldn't these threads be cleared off automatically? Do I need to look at some configurations to control this.

Any pointers please.

Comment: You can analyze a thread dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting OOM, you can tune the Operating System as well as the JVM. Please refer tuning performance documentation [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Tuning+Performance).

Comment: Thanks. I will check this.

Comment: I have gone through the performance tuning documentation. What I found out was that my dev server cannot support more than 1012 threads. I want to make APIM threads less than this number. By going through the above documentation I reduced the max threads in all the places so that it wont go more than 1012. Still APIM is trying to create more and more threads and ending up with error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. I am running all in one server (store, publisher, gateway and keymanager). Is there any way to keep the total threads less than 1000.

Comment: This is some kind of a known issue and it could happen if the max allowed processes per user called "nproc" is too low. Because of that JVM will fail and throws OOM. You can check nproc by running 'ulimit -u' command. You can change that value by editing /etc/security/limits.conf file. Format of the value is {username} hard nproc {value}. Make sure you reboot the server to apply the changes. You could also apply the changes by running the command in [1] without rebooting the server.
[1] - http://xmodulo.com/how-to-reload-sysctlconf.html

Comment: Thank you. Increased the process limit earlier but it was effective only for the root. APIM is under a different user and I had now set the limits explicitly for that user in limits.conf. All works and after around 1K threads APIM is not creating more number of threads.